# VS App Center build for Project in VisualStudio Online and Github

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I try to implement App Center build for my xamarin.forms Project. Difficulty I have is that my source Code is hosted on Visual Studio Online(Azure Devops as new Name) and github. So like below Project A and Project B are open-source Projects hosted in Github and referencing on Main Project

- Main Project (Azure Devops)
- Project A -Github
- Project B- Github

With that stucture if I create an automatic build on my Project, build is failing. Is there a way to go around this without creating nuget package for Project A and Project B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of "advanced" scenario's are not possible with App Center. App Center is targeting simple cases and beginning developers who just want to hook up their repo and build.

If you want to do this you need to create a NuGet package as you already mentioned yourself or move the whole pipeline into Azure DevOps where you can do more advanced stuff.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer Gerald. I also thought that but just wanted to make sure that there is possibility because as I know Github source Code build is also possible using Azure devops. so i thought that it might be a way around.

Comment: No problem! Would be great if you could mark it as an answer then as well, thanks!